# How to remove the squiggly lines from my VS 2019 Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, suppress-warnings, solution-explorer

I used to have Visual studio 2019 pro edition but this never occurred before. Now that I have the Enterprise edition, green squiggly lines appear under every folder or file that includes a warning. It is so annoying. How do I remove those lines from the Solution Explorer. I'm okay with it if they are inside the code.

[image: solution explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the warnings squiggly lines in Solution Explorer from the Visual Studio options.

- Go to Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Solution Error Visualizer.
- Uncheck the 'Underline items contains warnings'.

Options > Productivity Power Tools > Solution Error Visualizer

[image: Options > Productivity Power Tools > Solution Error Visualizer]